# WPMU Get value from db table of specific blog id and put it in html

Tags: php, html, css, database, wordpress

Do you think this code works to get a value from a specific subsite's table by its ID?

```
global $wpdb;

        $blogs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT blog_id FROM wp_blogs where blog_id > 1");

        foreach ($blogs as $blog) {

            $option_values = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_value FROM wp_" . $blog->blog_id . "_options WHERE option_name='plugin_app_color' ");

            foreach ($option_values as $value) {
                var_dump($value->option_value);
            }
        }
```

And if so, how can I put the value in CSS code in `<head>` in HTML?

Something like this:

```
<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
div { color: <?php echo $value ?>; 
}
</style>

</head>

</html>
```

I need to get a css value (in my case a hex color from an element) and put it in other elements by css class. This value is saved in the subsite database table.

**I would like to use a function in functions.php to do this.**

Thank you in advance.